# Problem installing apps

Tags: 16.04, repository

When I try to install something from Ubuntu Software Center I don't find anything.

For example, VLC. I tried to download it from the official website, and it takes me back to Ubuntu software. I tried from the terminal and it can't find the repository. It happens with any program except the programs that I already have, like Firefox.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1 on an i5 2410m and 8GB of RAM.

Comment: Please open the terminal and update your system with *sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade*. Post back the errors if any.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a fresh install there are repositories that needs to be updated.  Run these commands:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt install vlc
```